# Exotic bracket symbols for a math article

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, math-operators

I'm looking for a new type of "bracket" symbol for a math article, which is analogous but easily differentiated from $(\cdot),[\cdot],{\cdot},\langle \cdot\rangle,|\cdot|,<\cdot>$.

Does anyone have any ideas? (Are there any custom built symbols to this effect?). Crucially I would like it to look nice, and to have spacing rules appropriate for a bracket symbol.

For example, are there angle brackets like $\langle,\rangle$ with three segments instead of 2?

Comment: You could start out by looking at the [comprehensive list of symbols](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf). There are several sections starting on page 99 devoted to delimiters. It is also possible to design your own if there's something specific you have in mind.

Comment: @SandyG That's very helpful! I think the symbols "\lbrbrak" and "rbrbrak" would be perfect for me, but it seems to require that I "usepackage{stix}", but using this package also changes how the rest of my document looks. Is there a way to gain access to these symbols without changing the rest of the document?

Comment: @SandyG Fantastic! Thank you!